# Ignoring the load test contained in file 'xyz.loadtest' as it is not supported in Unit Test Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

Visual Studio is not able to discover and execute specific unit tests and giving below error while loading the tests :

Ignoring the load test contained in file 'xyz.loadtest' as it is not supported in Unit Test Explorer. To run this test, open the load test file and run it from its editor. For more information see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236838&clcid=0x409

I went thorough the mentioned reference but didn't find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by updating "MSTest.TestFramework" and "MSTest.TestAdapter" nuget packages to the latest version and setting up "Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture->x64".